# Significance of ground state energy in quantum chemistry

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I'm reading a paper that says "The fundamental goal in electronic-structure problems is to solve for the ground-state energy of many-body interacting fermionic Hamiltonians" (ref: https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.05018).

Why is the ground state energy so important in quantum chemistry?

Comment: Molecules spend the vast majority of their time in the ground state. Also, it's stable.

Comment: Adding to what @probably_someone said, maybe because the excited states can be calculated once you have the ground state, the opposite is pretty problematic.